# Change data type in Numpy and Nibabel

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to convert numpy arrays into Nifti file format using Nibabel. Some of my Numpy arrays have `dtype('<i8')` when it should be `dtype('uint8')` when Nibabel calls for the data type.

```
arr.get_data_dtype()
```

Does anyone know how to convert and save Numpy arrays' data type?

Comment: `'<i8' doesn't look like a structured array; that just the regular `int64`.  Have you tried `astype`?

Comment: The datatype of the original array is int64 but changes to '<i8' when loaded into Nibabel `arr = nib.Nifti1Image(np_arr, np.eye(4))`

Comment: `np.ones(3,'<i8').astype('uint8')` works for me

Comment: @hpaulj thanks! that's seems to work in the nib call as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question of the title is slightly different than the question in the text. So...

---

If you want to change the data-type of a numpy array `arr` to `np.int8`, you are looking for `arr.astype(np.int8)`.

Mind that you may lose precision due to data casting (see [astype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) documentation)

To save it afterwards you may want to see `?np.save` and `?np.savetxt` (or to check the library `pickle`, to save more general objects than numpy array).

---

If you want to change the data-type of a nifti image saved in `my_image.nii.gz`
you have to go for:

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np

image = nib.load('my_image.nii.gz')

# to be extra sure of not overwriting data:
new_data = np.copy(image.get_data())
hd = image.header

# in case you want to remove nan:
new_data = np.nan_to_num(new_data)

# update data type:
new_dtype = np.int8  # for example to cast to int8.
new_data = new_data.astype(new_dtype)
image.set_data_dtype(new_dtype)

# if nifty1
if hd['sizeof_hdr'] == 348:
    new_image = nib.Nifti1Image(new_data, image.affine, header=hd)
# if nifty2
elif hd['sizeof_hdr'] == 540:
    new_image = nib.Nifti2Image(new_data, image.affine, header=hd)
else:
    raise IOError('Input image header problem')

nib.save(new_image, 'my_image_new_datatype.nii.gz')
```

---

Finally if you have a numpy array `my_arr` and you want to save it into a nifti image with a given data-type `np.my_dtype`, you can do:

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np

new_image = nib.Nifti1Image(my_arr, np.eye(4))
new_image.set_data_dtype(np.my_dtype)

nib.save(new_image, 'my_arr.nii.gz')
```

Hope it helps!

---

NOTE: If you are using ITKsnap you may want to use `np.float32`, `np.float64`, `np.uint16`, `np.uint8`, `np.int16`, `np.int8`. Other choices may not produce images that can be open with this software.

Comment: This is now encoded in the function `set_new_data`, as part of the pip installable library nilabels https://github.com/SebastianoF/nilabels . Conflict of interest declaration: I made it!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could also do

```
import nibabel

img = nibabel.load(filename)
img.set_data_dtype(dtype)
img.to_filename(new_filename)
```

Comment: This does not work. This will create a garbled file as one also has to change the data in the img.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nilearn for a tidy solution. Here is an example if you want to change the data type of nifti image to int16:

```
from nilearn import image
import numpy as np

vol = image.load_img(input_file)
vol = image.new_img_like(vol, np.int16(vol.get_fdata()))
vol.to_filename(output_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Datatypes for .nii files can also be specified in the `.to_filename()` function:

```py
import nibabel as nib
new_image = nib.Nifti2Image(my_arr, affine)
new_image.to_filename(fn, dtype=np.uint8)
```